# Push notification problems with Back4App and APN Authentication Key

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, back4app

I'm using ParseServer with Back4App for an Android and iOS App. I implemented a Cloud Function on the server to send push notifications through Parse and it works for the Android app without any issues (for both debug and production apks).

With the iOS Version I am currently running into the following problem:
I created an APN Authentication Key that I uploaded to Back4App. In the process I indicated that this key is for a debug app, and sending push notifications via the Cloud Function to my iOS debug device works like a charm, no matter what device triggers the Cloud Function. This was sufficient for development.

I need to be able to get push notifications to both device types to troubleshoot together with my TestFlight testers in an open test I recently started.

For all TestFlight test devices, push notifications are not getting delivered - which is not surprising, given that the APN Key was uploaded to Back4App for debug apps only.

I thus reuploaded the APN Key and indicated that it is a production app, and now sending push notifications to the TestFlight testers works, but sending push notifications to my iOS debug test device does not.

I tried getting around this by changing the build scheme in Xcode from Debug to Release - but with a release version on my iOS debug device, the push notifications are still not being delivered to said device. I can see in my Parse Dashboard that they are being sent, but they are not getting delivered.

I am using a Notification Service Extension and set the Build Mode to Release there as well, but to no effect.

Changing the APN Authentication Key on Back4App back to Debug only allows me to receive push notifications again on my debug device.

I tried changing the APN Authentication Key (for either debug and production, since I cannot select both on Back4App) before force quitting the app, restarting it to get a new APN token saved to the ParseServer, and then sending the test notifications, also to no avail. I tried this for both my debug device and a TestFlight device, and it is always either my debug device (who gets the app straight from Xcode) or the TestFlight devices that are able to receive push notifications, never both.

I did not get around to trying it with APN Certificates for which I read that there are two distinct certificates for Production and Debug apps. While this option would be possible with Back4App, one big question remains - how do you implement push notifications both for debug and production apps in iOS with only one APN Authentication Key? And more specifically, how do you do that on Back4App?

Or are there any other ways around this issue besides the old APN Certificates? Since APN Authentication Keys are made out to be the future I'd rather implement it with that instead of the older APN Certificates.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to upload both the debug and production certificates and leave them existing at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround and what caused the issue:

Using APN Authentication Keys for push notifications is easier to implement and more convenient since keys don't expire, can be used across multiple apps and do not require the generation of independent development and production certificates.

But: An APN Authentication Key can only be used for EITHER development push notifications OR production push notifications (which is apparently intended by Apple).

No matter whether build settings are set to Release or Debug, a tethered physical device that gets any build straight from Xcode will always have the APN environment flag set to development - even manually setting the APN environment flag to production before building does not have an effect, it seems to be reset at build time and defaults to development. This means that my debug test device (physically connected to Xcode) can only receive development pushes, which explained my described issues.

When archiving a build and uploading it to TestFlight, the APN environment flag is automatically set to production; all TestFlight testers thus only receive production push notifications.

What I am doing to work around this is that I registered my debug test device as a TestFlight tester so that I can download my latest build from there and take advantage of production pushes. I registered this particular test device as its own group so that I can test builds only with that device that I do not want to immediately roll out to all other TestFlight users in my second (true) group of testers.

Does that mean I always need to archive any new builds and push it to my test device via TestFlight to try something new?

No, only for things that require push notifications. For everything else I still get the latest build straight from Xcode because all locally stored data (like a logged-in Parse User or Installation data) persists on my device, no matter whether I install a new version from Xcode directly or through TestFlight automated updates.

That way I can work as usual and only have to take the additional TestFlight step for any push notification-related features.

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing, is that back4app allows you to upload a "dev non production" authKey. And problem still exist. And they only allow you to upload one AUTHKEY, so it's confusing AF

Also on my android app, i get push notifications from back4app fine, except i don't get them when the app is terminated in android.

Also my i uploaded the same exact authkey into firebase, and i get push notification fine from firebase in ios if the app is open or closed.

moral of the story back4app is hackeyAF

[image]

Comment: Feel free to raise a support ticket. They might assist you with that.